# MongoDb find Object in a array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Can someone help me with a solution to find an array object inside the MongoDB document, I've tried a couple of methods but am still not able to get the object that I need I'm trying to query based on the user data e.g finding using user email and name, here is the document that I want to find array in the document.

```
{
"_id": "lfe78vlwncr",
"images": [],
"location": [28.1339088, -26.2098077],
"_p_category": "Category$ZjfUGGzbNb",

"image": "5d4663900459815806965d8af5392190_image.jpg",
"imageName": "5d4663900459815806965d8af5392190_image.jpg",
"imageThumb": "5d4663900459815806965d8af5392190_image.jpg",
"isHead": "1",
"storeNumber": null,
"twitter": null,
"superUser": null,
"youtube": null,

"user": {
    "email": "admin@tester.co",
    "name": "john"
},
"_created_at": "2022-03-15T08:17:46.769Z",

"status": "Approved",
"_wperm": ["*"],
"_rperm": ["*"],
"_acl": {
    "w": "true",
    "r": "true"
},
"bIsSales": "true",
"_updated_at": "2022-03-17T05:06:38.425Z",
"bShow": true,

"imageFour": "49217bd1ccf227f010562be0b9e0b889_image.jpg",
"imageThree": "998866aa6707b520f8a6d214351b6256_image.jpg",
"imageTwo": "a394516d65948af07033ac8812d225b8_image.jpg",
```

}

here is what I tried so far yet still not working.

```
db.collection("Place")
.find({

    user: {
        email: req.body.userEmail,
        name: req.body.userName
    }
})
.toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    res.json(result);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
db.collection("Place")
.find({
  'user.email': req.body.userEmail,
  'user.name': req.body.userName
})
.toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    res.json(result);
});
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tujE7G22W_F)

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: it does work https://mongoplayground.net/p/tujE7G22W_F